# Parsing Nested JSON using SCALA

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, nested

I am looking to inject Telemetry data and the output is a multi layered nested JSON file.  I am interested in very specific fields but I am not able to parse the JSON file to get to the data.

Data Sample:

> { "version_str": "1.0.0", "node_id_str": "router-01", "encoding_path":
>   "sys/intf", "collection_id": 241466, "collection_start_time": 0,
>   "collection_end_time": 0, "msg_timestamp": 0, "subscription_id": [ ],
>   "sensor_group_id": [ ], "data_source": "DME", "data": {
>   "interfaceEntity": { "attributes": { "childAction": "", "descr": "",
>   "dn": "sys/intf", "modTs": "2017-09-19T13:24:14.751+00:00",
>   "monPolDn": "uni/fabric/monfab-default", "persistentOnReload": "true",
>   "status": "" }, "children": [ { "l3LbRtdIf": { "attributes": {
>   "adminSt": "up", "childAction": "", "descr": "Nothing", "id":
>   "lo103", "linkLog": "default", "modTs":
>   "2017-11-06T23:18:02.974+00:00", "monPolDn":
>   "uni/fabric/monfab-default", "name": "", "persistentOnReload": "true",
>   "rn": "lb-[lo103]", "status": "", "uid": "0" }, "children": [ {
>   "ethpmLbRtdIf": { "attributes": { "currErrIndex": "4294967295",
>   "ifIndex": "335544423", "iod": "14", "lastErrors": "0,0,0,0",
>   "operBitset": "", "operDescr": "Nothing", "operMtu": "1500",
>   "operSt": "up", "operStQual": "none", "rn": "lbrtdif" } } }, {
>   "nwRtVrfMbr": { "attributes": { "childAction": "", "l3vmCfgFailedBmp":
>   "", "l3vmCfgFailedTs": "00:00:00:00.000", "l3vmCfgState": "0",
>   "modTs": "2017-11-06T23:18:02.945+00:00", "monPolDn": "",
>   "parentSKey": "unspecified", "persistentOnReload": "true", "rn":
>   "rtvrfMbr", "status": "", "tCl": "l3Inst", "tDn": "sys/inst-default",
>   "tSKey": "" } } } ] } }, { "l3LbRtdIf": { "attributes": { "adminSt":
>   "up", "childAction": "", "descr": "Nothing", "id": "lo104",
>   "linkLog": "default", "modTs": "2018-01-25T15:54:20.367+00:00",
>   "monPolDn": "uni/fabric/monfab-default", "name": "",
>   "persistentOnReload": "true", "rn": "lb-[lo104]", "status": "", "uid":
>   "0" }, "children": [ { "ethpmLbRtdIf": { "attributes": {
>   "currErrIndex": "4294967295", "ifIndex": "335544424", "iod": "77",
>   "lastErrors": "0,0,0,0", "operBitset": "", "operDescr":
>   "Nothing", "operMtu": "1500", "operSt": "up", "operStQual":
>   "none", "rn": "lbrtdif" } } }, { "nwRtVrfMbr": { "attributes": {
>   "childAction": "", "l3vmCfgFailedBmp": "", "l3vmCfgFailedTs":
>   "00:00:00:00.000", "l3vmCfgState": "0", "modTs":
>   "2018-01-25T15:53:55.757+00:00", "monPolDn": "", "parentSKey":
>   "unspecified", "persistentOnReload": "true", "rn": "rtvrfMbr",
>   "status": "", "tCl": "l3Inst", "tDn": "sys/inst-default", "tSKey": ""
>   } } } ] } }, { "l3LbRtdIf": { "attributes": { "adminSt": "up",
>   "childAction": "", "descr": "Nothing", "id": "lo101",
>   "linkLog": "default", "modTs": "2017-11-13T21:39:58.910+00:00",
>   "monPolDn": "uni/fabric/monfab-default", "name": "",
>   "persistentOnReload": "true", "rn": "lb-[lo101]", "status": "", "uid":
>   "0" }, "children": [ { "ethpmLbRtdIf": { "attributes": {
>   "currErrIndex": "4294967295", "ifIndex": "335544421", "iod": "12",
>   "lastErrors": "0,0,0,0", "operBitset": "", "operDescr":
>   "Nothing", "operMtu": "1500", "operSt": "up", "operStQual":
>   "none", "rn": "lbrtdif" } } }, { "nwRtVrfMbr": { "attributes": {
>   "childAction": "", "l3vmCfgFailedBmp": "", "l3vmCfgFailedTs":
>   "00:00:00:00.000", "l3vmCfgState": "0", "modTs":
>   "2017-11-13T21:39:58.880+00:00", "monPolDn": "", "parentSKey":
>   "unspecified", "persistentOnReload": "true", "rn": "rtvrfMbr",
>   "status": "", "tCl": "l3Inst", "tDn": "sys/inst-default", "tSKey": ""
>   } } } ] } }, { "l3LbRtdIf": { "attributes": { "adminSt": "up",
>   "childAction": "", "descr": "\"^:tier2:if:loopback:mgmt:l3\"", "id":
>   "lo0", "linkLog": "default", "modTs": "2017-09-25T20:29:54.003+00:00",
>   "monPolDn": "uni/fabric/monfab-default", "name": "",
>   "persistentOnReload": "true", "rn": "lb-[lo0]", "status": "", "uid":
>   "0" }, "children": [ { "ethpmLbRtdIf": { "attributes": {
>   "currErrIndex": "4294967295", "ifIndex": "335544320", "iod": "11",
>   "lastErrors": "0,0,0,0", "operBitset": "", "operDescr":
>   "\"^:tier2:if:loopback:mgmt:l3\"", "operMtu": "1500", "operSt": "up",
>   "operStQual": "none", "rn": "lbrtdif" } } }, { "nwRtVrfMbr":...

I am interested in these attributes:

```
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- rmonIfIn: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- attributes: struct (nullable = true                                                                                        )
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- broadcastPkts: string (nullabl                                                                                        e = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- discards: string (nullable = t                                                                                        rue)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- errors: string (nullable = tru                                                                                        e)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- multicastPkts: string (nullabl                                                                                        e = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- nUcastPkts: string (nullable =                                                                                         true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- packetRate: string (nullable =                                                                                         true)
```

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession    
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode
import spark.implicits._

val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate

val df = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").json("file:///usr/local/Projects/out.txt")

val mapDF = df.select($"node_id_str" as "nodename", $"data".getItem("InterfaceEntity").getItem("children").getItem("l1PhysIf").getItem("children").getItem("element"))
```

I keep getting an error when I attempt to get any deeper, I keep getting data type error:

```
stringJsonDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [nestDevice: string]
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`data`.`InterfaceEntity`.`children`.`l1PhysIf`.`children`['element']' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires integral type, however, ''element'' is of string type.;;
```

Comment: You should post a [mcve] or at least a full schema.

Comment: Is there a way to attach a document?

Comment: No, you have to use code blocks.

Comment: @user3521305 was my answer of any help? If not please provide some feedback otherwise can you please accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Gson Library which is used to work with json. You can convert any object to json and of course do it in reverse. here is an example for doing so:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<Map<Long, String>> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<>();
//here you can new some maps and add them to the listOfMaps. 
String listOfMapsInJsonFormat = gson.toJson(listOfMaps);
```

above sample code is for converting an object to json. To do the reverse job you can check below one too:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
List list = gson.fromJson(listOfMapsInJsonFormat, List.class);
```

the above code will change your input json string to a list which contains maps. Of course there may be a difference in the type of the map you have had before converting the original object to json and the one gson builds the object from json string. to avoid that you can use TypeToken class:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken()<ArrayList<Map<>>>{}.getType();
ArrayList<Map<>> = gson.fromJson(listOfMapsInJsonFormat, type);
```

Comment: That data i am working with is already a json format.  My issue is the ability to to get to the data that is several layers deep.

Comment: just continue reading to the end of my answer. I'd just described how gson helps to convert from json to object(deserialization) and even the reverse direction(serialization). you can do something like the second code sample: gson.fromJson(jsonString, Map.class). then iterate on the map to find the data you want to extract.

Answer (score 0):

Since the fields are part of multiple nested arrays the logic would assume that you are interested in all iterations of those fields per record (so if one record contains *n* `rmonIfIn` items due to nested arrays, you would be interested in each of them?)

If so it makes sense to `explode` these nested arrays and process the expanded dataframe.

Based on your code and incomplete json example it could look like something like this:

```scala
val nested = df
  .select(explode($"data.InterfaceEntity").alias("l1"))
  .select(explode($"l1.l1PhysIf").alias("l2"))
  .select($"l2.rmonIfIn.attributes".alias("l3"))
  .select($"l3.broadcastPkts", $"l3.discards", $"l3.errors", $"l3.multicastPkts", $"l3.packetRate")
```

Returning a dataframe that could look like

```
+-------------+--------+------+-------------+----------+
|broadcastPkts|discards|errors|multicastPkts|packetRate|
+-------------+--------+------+-------------+----------+
|1            |1       |1     |1            |1         |
|2            |2       |2     |2            |2         |
|3            |3       |3     |3            |3         |
|4            |4       |4     |4            |4         |
+-------------+--------+------+-------------+----------+
```